# How do I fix my button style, s.t. I have some margin between the text and the button itself?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a touchable opacity element which is inside a view. In this touchable opacity I placed a text element. The problem which I am facing is that the touchable opacity width is the same as the text width without any margin between the text and the button. (see the attached photo). Here is my code:

```
<View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonStyle}
            activeOpacity={0.5}
            onPress={() => someMethod()}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Blah blah</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

and my styles:

```
buttonStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#5CB3FF',
    height: 40,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buttonTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  buttonWrapper: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    margin: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
```

I would like to have some space between the text and the button border

[image]

EDIT: I tried with the following style

```
buttonTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    margin: 10
  },
```

but it still doesnt leave any space

Comment: I see styles.title but you have buttonTextStyle

Comment: yes, my mistake, but it still doesnt leave space

Comment: USe padding on the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about ??

```
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Margin to add space outside of the element
Use Padding to add space inside the element by the border